# What is the easiest way to move each value into its own unique index within an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with nested values and I need each value to be unique. The values are always seperated by commas. So the following input would return:

Input =>   `["1", "1", "1,2", "1", "1", "1,34", "1,34", "1,2", "1,2", "1,2", "1,2", "1,2", "1,2", "1,2", "1,2", "1,2", "1,2", "1,2", "1,2", "1,2", "1,2", "1,2", "1,2", "1,2", "1"]`

Output=>
 `["1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1,", "34", "1", "34", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "12", "1"`]

Comment: If any of the answers solved your problem, consider marking one of them as Accepted to indicate that the issue is resolved :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split by commas, then spread into `[].concat` to flatmap:

```js
const input = ["1", "1", "1,2", "1", "1", "1,34", "1,34", "1,2", "1,2", "1,2", "1,2", "1,2", "1,2", "1,2", "1,2", "1,2", "1,2", "1,2", "1,2", "1,2", "1,2", "1,2", "1,2", "1,2", "1"];
console.log(
  [].concat(...input.map(str => str.split(',')))
);
```

In newer browsers, you can use `Array.prototype.flatMap` instead of the `concat` spread trick:

```
input.flatMap(str => str.split(','));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use join and split

```
const input = ["1", "1", "1,2", "1", "1", "1,34", "1,34", "1,2", "1,2", "1,2", "1,2", "1,2", "1,2", "1,2", "1,2", "1,2", "1,2", "1,2", "1,2", "1,2", "1,2", "1,2", "1,2", "1,2", "1"]
const output = input.join(',').split(',')
console.log(output)
```